# Detect change of Validators in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to detect a change (add/remove) in control validators.
For example, I have a control without any validator, and then I want to add "Validators.required".

```js
this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
    name: [null]
});

// And then, let's say 1 second later, something like this happens:
setTimeout(() => {
  this.formGroup.controls['name'].setValidators(Validators.required);
}, 1000);
```

In the template:

```html
<input myDirective formControlName="name">
```

In the directive `myDirective` I want to detect when the `setValidators` happen, or more general, I want to know when validators for that control have changed.

In the constructor of `myDirective` I inject the NgControl so I have access to it:

```js
constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {
}
```

But now I cannot see how to achieve that.

- I have a working solution, using `ngDoCheck` and `this.ngControl.control.validator({} as AbstractControl)` to be able to retrieve the validators, and then compare to the original validators, etc. But this is ugly, since this function is executed many times unnecessarily.
- I have also tried with es6 Proxy (proxying `this.ngControl.control`) but I had no luck, I am not notified when the validators change.

What is the best way to achieve this?
Why is Angular not exposing an Observable for that?

---

Edit:

I have seen that if I do:

```js
this.formGroup.controls['name'].setValidators(Validators.required);
this.formGroup.controls['name'].updateValueAndValidity();
```

Then in the `myDirective` directive I can subscribe to `this.ngControl.control.statusChanges`, and then compare the old validator(s) with the new validator(s) to see if some have been added/removed, etc.

Still not ideal, because a status change does not mean that validator functions have changed, but a decent solution.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Usually we apply validators without any delay but we show the potential error of a field or form only if it is in status "touched" for instance, meaning we wait for some user interaction before displaying the errors.

Comment: If a validator is added (or removed) dynamically to a control, I would like the directive (or component) respond to the change. Very basic case: Imagine I have an <input myDirective formControlName="..."> with a directive that adds a clear button on the right if the control has _not_ a required validator, otherwise the directive does not append the clear button because it is required.

Comment: I was more questionning the need for dynamically adding/removing validator

Comment: I have layouts that depend on value/existance of specific validators. Validators can change depending on other selected values on the form. I have a dropdown that, depending on the selected value makes a field required or not, and let's say I want to dinamically add an asterisk on the righ of that field... Furthermore, all of this is in a very generic environment that handles these changes on validators